# react setState Array async

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I have an array in this.state.userlist

The user list is based on the callback push user object

So I used it

```
  if(type ==='add')
    
    {
    
    const pairs = this.state.userlist.slice();
    
    pairs.push(someUser);
    
    this.setState({ userlist:pairs });
    
    }else if(type ==='delete')
    
    {
    
    this.setState({userlist: this.state.userlist.filter(item => item.userId != userId };)
    
    }
```

After that in the case of frequent add or delete, the user list array will occasionally be inconsistent.
also i used the array in dom it look like :

```
this.state.userlist.map(item=>{
<div>{item.name}</div>
})
```

Please help me

Comment: sorry it's  this.state.userlist

Comment: the question looks like sync safe lock in C# or java , but the js is async . callback function in anywhere. i am so sad :(.

Comment: try this: this.setstate((this.state.userlist) => [...this.state.userlist, someUser]) in add instead of the three lines

Comment: i try it: this.setState((state)=>{ return userlist:state.userlist.concat(someuser)}), but it also wrong at sometimes. :(

Comment: I think we'd need a lot more context here, like where is the logic from the first snippet in a component and what is triggering it? I see you also are missing React keys for that second snippet, so if you are rendering from that and add and removing and otherwise mutating the underlying array data structure you will see odd/poor results. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?